# rank decomposition with easy-to-understand condition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

Harville ("Matrix algebra from a statistician's perspective", 1997, p.383, Theorem 17.2.4) states as follows:

> Let $A$ represent an $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ an $m \times p$ matrix.
> If $\mathcal{C}(A)$ and $\mathcal{C}(B)$ are $essentially$ $disjoint$, then
> $ rank(A, B) = rank(A) + rank(B) $

where $\mathcal{C}(A)$ denotes the column space of $A$ and $essentially$ $disjoint$ means that $\mathcal{C}(A) \cap \mathcal{C}(B)=0$.

My question is how the condition $\mathcal{C}(A) \cap \mathcal{C}(B)=0$ can be rephrased in a way that is easy to understand. Is $\mathcal{C}(A) \cap \mathcal{C}(B)=0$ equivalent to $Ax \neq By$ for any $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: No, it means $Ax\ne By$ when $Ax\ne0$ and $By\ne0$.

Comment: Many thanks. It seems that $Ax \neq 0$ excludes the case where $A$ is rank deficient. So, I'm wondering how rank deficiency case is treated in the disjoint condition. Is is simply excluded?

Comment: @user0131 The second comment's definition of "essentially disjoint" holds even if $A$ and/or $B$ are rank-deficient. Note that the statement here is essentially that **if** $x,y$ are such that $Ax \neq 0$ and $By \neq 0$, **then** $Ax \neq By$. $A$ being rank-deficient might imply that $Ax = 0$ holds for some non-zero $x$, but it is still possible for $A$ and $B$ to be essentially disjoint.

Comment: Many thanks. So, "essentially disjoint" means that $Ax \neq By$ when $Ax \neq 0$ and $By \neq 0$. Am I right?

Comment: I'm wondering if $Ax \neq By$ holds for any $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$ is sufficient to have $rank[A,B]=rank[A]+rank[B]$. I want to know a sufficient condition to have this rank decomposition.